# Are "First Question" reviews supposed to take 5-10 seconds?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-abuse, first-questions

A particular individual has given me cause to pay attention to them, in multiple ways. One way is the following:

Their actions log is full of "Looks OK" reviews spaced about 10 seconds apart. I see the occasional "reviewed" verdict but no *other* verdicts, never ever, not even on first questions that *at least* have a formatting issue (and no edit).

It's a pattern. I don't know what to call it, whether to call attention to it, or how to do that. There is a chance that this particular individual simply *is* that practiced (hence quick) with reviewing first questions but there is no chance that so many first questions are OK.

Comment: Looks like there are a few reviewers clicking "Looks OK" for all reviews, despite whether the questions are even questions, let alone on-topic.

Comment: I could absolutely see someone getting reviews done in 5-10 seconds if the results are *mostly not* "Looks OK". With practice, applying high standards is surprisingly fast. Things that don't meet those standards are very noticeable.

Comment: Perhaps someone trying to get review badges rather than add actual value of the review actions.  Reviews are actually harder that it would seem IMHO unlesss they are just totally missing code etc.

Comment: @Adriaan, I'd rephrase it as: running for _another_ quick 1k reviews for the _next_ gold badge. They are awarded multiple times.

Comment: I believe I saw three strategies to fill the daily review limit: looks OK everything, vote up everything, vote down everything.

Comment: Robo-reviewing has been a problem on some sites in the past. It wouldn't surprise me if you had found another one.

Comment: I just found a user that averages 4 seconds a review, and their last *14 pages* of reviews were all "looks ok". I'm amazed that they haven't been tripped up by something as yet. Some of the content that is "ok" is far from it...

Comment: I think you found the one I'm thinking of. you won't find anything different even if you clicked on to page 50 like I just did. I don't think the automated defenses are effective.

Comment: *480~* pages of reviews in the last year, averaging about 28 a day, @ChristophRackwitz ? Almost *every single one* a "looks ok"?

Comment: I guess it's 5-10 seconds because they're opening the content in a separate tab to see if it's an audit, or else they'd fail every one of them. I guess you can get really fast at that cycle too with enough practice. Open in a tab, check, hit looks ok/skip button.

Comment: personally, if I were so inclined, I'd just write a userscript to fetch the page and check whether it's a trap or not. *and* slap a random verdict on each review. that'd make quick work of the review queue. and while I'm at it, I might even come up with simple metrics that'll actually correlate with question quality, so the verdict isn't complete bogus. maybe I'd even get some AI involved and make it learn from a few examples. we're all programmers here, aren't we...

Comment: This is what Stack Exchange gets for asking volunteers to do review.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I don't believe we are actually, that tends to come up in discussions about the survey. But regardless of the label we are still (mostly) people, and people differ in how big their brains are.

Comment: I don't think this is a matter of brain power. it's a matter of someone's attitude towards society/communities, the *people* that make up the community, and the expectations and rules therein (like "don't cheat"). there are arguments to be made for positive, negative, and no correlation between brain power and an individual's inclination to cheating.

Comment: FWIW, I *suspect* the user in question in the above comments is now review banned (as they suddenly stopped reviewing). No idea how long that'll remain.

Comment: nope. last review 3 hours ago. he did go quiet on the reviews after I brought this issue to attention (also flagging), but recently continued with more variation on the verdicts, which makes judging the quality (or lack thereof) harder. perhaps it was temporary. in any case, I didn't see any notices. -- are you perhaps thinking of another user that isn't the one I'm thinking of? -- he does have a habit of changing his names. for a long time he went by the name of a manga/anime character, then by the name of a country.

Comment: Looks like we're thinking of different users then. @ChristophRackwitz .

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you want to call attention to something, raise a custom flag and explain your worries. You'd want to mention some specific posts where you think Looks OK was definitely the wrong action.